# Recyclerview : ImageView in CardView fits center and hides other textviews before scrolling

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to present a CardView with 3 textviews and a imageView inside a RecyclerView. Problem is that if before you start scrolling imageView is filled completely in cardview and the textviews are hidden even though the relative layout inside the cardview is supposed to keep the image on the left side. After scrolling some of the cardviews will end up looking how i want them to, if i sort the List and update the adapter all the cardviews except the last work like i want them to.

Here's the relevant XML's:
Cardview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="4dp">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="1dp"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cv_photo"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cv_name"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cv_photo"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cv_number"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cv_photo"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cv_name"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cv_date"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cv_photo"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cv_number"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/ProfileRecycler"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="491dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewbox"
        android:clipToPadding="false"

        />
```

Adapter code (has everything that's necessary)

```
@Override
    public ProfileViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(segruppe.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.profileview,viewGroup,false);
        ProfileViewHolder holder = new ProfileViewHolder(view);
        return holder;

    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProfileViewHolder ProfileViewHolder,int i){
        profileViewHolder.name.setText(profiles.get(i).getName());
        profileViewHolder.number.setText(String.valueOf(profiles.get(i).getNumber()));
        profileViewHolder.dato.setText(profiles.get(i).getDate().toString());
        if(profiles.get(i).getImage()!=null)
        Glide.with(context).load(profiles.get(i).getImage()).into(profileViewHolder.image);
    }
```

Fragment code for creating the cardview recycler:

```
profileRecycler = getView().findViewById(R.id.ProfileRecycler);
profileAdapter = new ProfileAdapter(getContext(),profileList);
GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),4, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
profileRecycler.setLayoutManager(glm);
profileRecycler.setAdapter(profileAdapter);
```

Can anyone see what is going wrong here? (Might be worth mentioning that if there's no imageView in the cardview then it remains completely static during and after scrolling like it's supposed to)

Comment: Change the hight of your cardview layout to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: try giving fix height and width to the imageview

Comment: Change `LinearLayout` height to `wrap_content` of list item.

Comment: thanks giving a fixed height to the imageview was enough :)